# Invoke Java Adapter in Desktop Browser Environment MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I want to execute a java code in MobileFirst Client App Desktop Environment.

In this link I can invoke Java classes from the adapter but I don't want that method since I need to update the war file in our server if I do this.
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/server-side-development/using-java-adapters/

I want a way without updating the war file in the server.

I also tried using WLResourceRequest to invoke a Java Adapter but its not applicable in desktop environment.
Is there a way to execute a java code aside from the ones I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v7.x, the only way to execute Java code is when the class resides in the .war file that gets deployed to the server.

The Desktop environment in v7.1 does not support Java adapters. The only way is to use Java in JavaScript adapters (See: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/javascript-adapters/using-java-adapters/) but this, too, requires the Java code to reside in the war file.

In v8.0, however, there is no more war file deployment and Java adapters support the web platform (which means both mobile web and desktop browser).  Consider upgrading.

Comment: Our MFP server is v7.0, and as much as possible we don't want to update our existing war file in the server, but thanks a lot for confirming that it can't be done in this version.